# How to merge a list of tables with different columns in kdb/q into one table effeciently

Tags: kdb

I know I can do

```
raze table_list
```

But that require every single table in the table list with the same columns.

For my use case, I can accept adding columns with null values, if that column doesn't exist in all tables. In that case, I can do

```
(uj) over table_list
```

But this line of code is very slow. nowhere as fast as raze.

Is there an efficient way of merging all tables, even if they don't all have the same columns?

Comment: Any chance that you know the full schema in advance? This would allow you to add each intermediate result to a full schema (possibly in parallel?) and simplify the problem.

Comment: @user20349 I want to write a generic functin that doesn't depend on schema though..

Comment: You probably can't have it both ways......for it to be generic you have to sacrifice some speed.....for speed you need conforming schema. One option to consider is to delve into the inner workings of uj. The built-in joins are usually built to cover a lot of different use-cases and can be slower as a result. You may be able to make a custom version of uj which strips out the parts you don't need to make it work for your use-case. Then the `(uj/)` form might be more performant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To counter my comment above (and to repeat what I wrote on the google group):

You'll never get as fast as raze with conforming tables but using global append (if you can accept the creation of a global) can be an improvement on uj over:

```
/conforming tabs
n:1000000;
tabs:{flip`col1`col2`col3`col4`col5`col6!(n?100i;n?100j;n?.z.D;n?10f;n?.z.P;n?5h)}each til 10

q)\ts raze tabs
82 570426736

/non-conforming tabs
nctabs:{flip(6?`4)!(n?100i;n?100j;n?.z.D;n?10f;n?.z.P;n?5h)}each til 10

q)\ts a:(uj/)nctabs
5560 11729374832

/global append
q)\ts {t::(uj/)0#'x;{t,:x}each x}nctabs
3146 356520224

q)a~t
1b
```